# Can anyone tell me what type of encoding this is

Tags: image, encoding

I got a picture and it is saved as `.txt`. Can anyone tell me how I can find out how it was encoded? The first 4 lines are below. It was used in a c# project as a `.bmp`

> iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADcAAAA3CAIAAAAnuUURAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACx
>   jwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAACIjSURBVGhDTZcFUNTt9/Z5nsega3fZTpYtll2W
>   XLqXRpAQlEZRCRGVkJIWULpLukUaERUDEcQAARXsbjHAQOL73uj8f/MyZ+65ZwdmP1znXOecW0hC
>   DI5GKVDZBm5Z9VQjLwmiBkHTXt7AB0bTRikayimakHXcJYmaKLbRJlkiimUoiWfRCBQTJR4Whd+3

Comment: You say right in your question it was used as a bmp, so I think that'd be a good/easy first test. If it isn't that, then try other common image extensions, jpg/gif/PNG etc, etc...

Answer (score 1):

The key thing here is that you have an image, which on the disk is saved as a sequence of 1's and 0's, just like anything else on the disk. The key to decoding the image is knowing the image format, which is like the dictionary which allows you to interpret the 1's and 0's.

The first four lines, as text, will likely not be helpful in this task. You effectively said "take this information stored on disk as 1's and 0's that definitely do not represent text, *and interpret them as text*" It would be just as helpful to have the first four lines of 1's and 0's, and it would be more helpful to have **all** the lines of 1's and 0's.

The best way to solve your problem is:

1. Remove the `.txt` file extension
2. Try adding on each of the common image file extensions (`.bmp`, `.jpg`, `.gif`, etc.) and open the image with that file extension

The file extension that allows you to successfully open the image (it opens and is not meaningless noise) is the image's encoding. I strongly suspect that it will be `.bmp` (unless somewhere, something or someone converted it to a different format)